# latex - including a landscape pdf

Tags: latex

Having no end of trouble including a large landscape pdf in a portrait .tex document (using pdflatex).

When it does show up, only the leftmost end of the pdf shows up, now matter how small i make the scale. And i cant seem to get it to show in landscape mode at all...

Is anything wrong with the code i am using?

```
\begin{landscape}
\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{Appendix2.pdf}
\end{landscape}
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You may want to have a look at the [`pdfpages` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages?lang=en) which "sim­pli­fies the in­clu­sion of ex­ter­nal multi-page PDF doc­u­ments in LATEX doc­u­ments".

To include pages as landscape you can use the following:

```
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\includepdf[landscape=true]{circuit.pdf}
```

Comment: `\includepdf[pages=-,landscape=true]{circuit.pdf}` if the include is more than one page

Answer (score 21):

You can rotate included figures with `angle`, so for your case something like

```
\includegraphics[scale=0.1,angle=90]{Appendix2.pdf}
```

The angle is in degrees; maybe you need to use `angle=-90` instead.

As for *"when it does show up, only the leftmost end of the pdf shows up"*, you might have a problem with the bounding box, but this really depends on how you create the file.

Comment: I think that was it - when i got it to show the bounding box, i could only see the top left corners.. would fix itself no matter what code i tried. strange.

Answer (score 3):

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2739710/6608257) very interesting. To have landscape, just add `angle=-90`. `\includepdf[pages={1}, angle=-90]{xxxxxx.pdf}`, and that is all. Have fun !!!