# Combine multiple pages of .pdf into RMarkdown

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

I am using RMarkdown to pull various .pdf's into one central file. These .pdfs are multiple pages in length. The code that I am using is:

```
---
title: <center> <h1>Analysis Data</h1> </center>
mainfont: Arial
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
sansfont: Arial
fig_crop: false
toc: true
classoption: landscape
fontsize: {10}
geometry: margin=0.30in
header-includes:
- \usepackage{booktabs} 
- \usepackage{sectsty} \sectionfont{\centering}
- \renewcommand{\contentsname}{}\vspace{-2cm} 
---
# File One
\begin{center} 
\includegraphics[width=9.5in]{~/Desktop/DatasetOne.pdf} 
\end{center}
\newpage
# File Two 
\begin{center} 
\includegraphics[width=9.5in]{~/Desktop/DatasetTwo.pdf} 
\end{center}
```

However, when I knit the final .pdf together, only the first page of each .pdf document ("DatasetOne.pdf" and "DatasetTwo.pdf") are included and not the entire document.

Is it possible to pull through the entire .pdf's rather than just the first page?

Thank you.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739159/inserting-a-pdf-file-in-latex

Comment: Unfortunately, when I try to use the pdfpages package, I get the following error: `! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.137 ...esktop/DatasetOne.pdf}

pandoc: Error producing PDF
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
Execution halted`

Comment: I was able to get your example working on my end, see my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm able to successfully include two different multi-page PDFs in your example document using `pdfpages`:

```
---
title: <center> <h1>Analysis Data</h1> </center>
mainfont: Arial
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
sansfont: Arial
fig_crop: false
toc: true
classoption: landscape
fontsize: {10}
geometry: margin=0.30in
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{booktabs} 
  - \usepackage{sectsty} \sectionfont{\centering}
  - \renewcommand{\contentsname}{}\vspace{-2cm} 
  - \usepackage{pdfpages}
---

# File One

\includepdf[pages={-}]{pdf1.pdf}

\newpage

# File Two 

\includepdf[pages={-}]{pdf2.pdf}
```