# Inserting a pdf file in latex #2

Tags: pdf, latex, pdflatex

Referring to a previous question
[Inserting a pdf file in latex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739159/inserting-a-pdf-file-in-latex)
I'd like to ask how to insert a PDF page into a latex document by filling exactly one page.

If I include a page with design elements that extent to zero margin off the page edges, the solution provided in the link will result in the following, adding white margins of different sizes to the included page:
[image]
how do do this propably?
i did workaround-solve it by

```
\includepdf[noautoscale = true,scale=1.03 ]{<file>}
```

but this dos not precisely match the old page edges with the new ones. is there a clean version?

Solutions that did *not* bring the desired results:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/105589/insert-pdf-file-in-latex-document

Thanks!

Comment: Using `\includepdf` the way you do will include the page as-is, inserting it in your document, not overlaying it on the existing page size. Can you provide a complete, minimal document that replicates your results? Something we can copy-and-paste-and-compile and see exactly what your issue is? It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`. Also post the PDF somewhere.

Comment: Thank for your comment. you actually made me make a minimal example, and it perfectly works. so it probably is not a matter of the \includepdf, but of my documents. Thanks for making me help myself :)

Comment: Thank for your comment. you actually made me make a minimal example, and it perfectly works. so it probably is not a matter of the \includepdf, but of my documents. Thanks for making me help myself :)
[edit]
so i found that the to-be-inserted page i created with the a4paper option of the geometry package. when I compiled the host PDF with that option the result is as desired, otherwise not. interestingly, in all cases the paper size in all cases is exactly 210x297mm

since the real host document is a 150 page thesis, i am not going to change the used packages and go with my workaround.

Comment: 210mm x 297mm is exactly A4; see [Paper sizes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_size).

Answer (score 0):

To adjust the width and height for your pdf pages. First you should use `noautoscale` to be able to use width and height.

Remark: don't use `fitpaper=true` or `trim=Left Bottom Right Top` because they are for geometry page not to adjust your pdf pages.

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage[]{pdfpages}
 
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages={1},noautoscale,width=5cm,height=10cm]{your.pdf}
\end{document}
```